# laravel returning whole object when outputing

Tags: php, laravel

I ran into a problem and I don't know what to do next. So I'm trying to create a category-subcategory relation and list all subcategories under their parents, it works but I can't get the name of a subcategory as I'm getting this

```
[{"id":2,"name":"dadasda","category_id":2,"created_at":"2017-05-16 09:38:49","updated_at":"2017-05-16 09:38:49"},{"id":2,"name":"djhasjkdhaskjd","category_id":2,"created_at":"2017-05-16 09:56:07","updated_at":"2017-05-16 09:56:07"}]
```

when i try to output it like this

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{$category->name}}</div>
    </div>

    <p>{{$category->subcategory}}</p>

@endforeach
```

but if for example, i try to do it like this

```
{{$category->subcategory->name}}
```

I get this error

```
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /Users/admin/Desktop/LaraProjects/cadilab/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
```

I'm using this to create a relation

```
public function subcategory()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Subcategory', 'App\Category',
        'id', 'category_id', 'id'
    );
}
```

Comment: show how are you fetching the data

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How are you executing the query?

Comment: You can use `with` to get the relation data (in your case, subcategory). `Category::with('subcategory')` - It's something like this.

Comment: i just use get() in route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Category model**

```
public function subcategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Subcategory', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

**View**

```
//if used hasOne
$category->subcategory->name    

//if used hasMany
foreach($category->subcategory as $subcategory) {
    $subcategory->name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the collection you provided, you are getting multiple records, so that means that currently you have set it up that every category can have many subcategories. If this is correct, you are missing a extra foreach.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{$category->name}}</div>
    </div>

    @foreach($category as $subcategory)

    <p>{{$subcategory->name}}</p>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

PS: This can result in the N+1 problem, so make sure to eager load the relationships.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading